# Windows 8 doesn't boot up after trying to boot Ubuntu from USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8

Two nights ago I tried booting Ubuntu off a USB drive after I upgraded to Windows 8.

This sent my computer into some weird panic mode, and it took me three hours to get Windows to boot up properly. Windows was working fine until last night. It was then stuck on the login screen for 45 minutes.

I tried restarting because I thought the system just hung, but the same thing that happened a couple nights ago happened again — I left it running all night as I was sleeping and it wasnt able to boot up until 9 AM this morning (11 hours!).

Is this because I tried booting Ubuntu? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does it boot to Windows normally if the USB device with Ubuntu is not connected?

Comment: What laptop do you have?  There have been reports of the Ubuntu UEFI boot [bricking some laptops](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557)...

Comment: can you still get into ubuntu and if so can you access some boot logs, that might give you something to go on... I have had mixed luck when mixing windows 8 and ubuntu, sometimes they dont like to play together nicely, btw, i have this weird paranoia that m$ is trying very hard to bully against ubuntu in the first place, but like i said thats just my paranoia

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that you accidently damaged your Windows 8 boot information.

One way to correct this problem can be as follows:

- Boot into Ubuntu again from USB
- Choose the try Ubuntu option so you can actually use the live OS
- Connect to a network
- Open terminal (Ctrl+T)
- Run the following commands:

  add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

  apt-get update

  apt-get install boot-repair

  boot-repair
- This will run the boot-repair utility
- It will recognize Windows and install Grub temporairly allowing you to boot into Windows
- Restart and boot into Windows
- Download program called EasyBCD (Google it).
- Open EasyBCD, it will allow you to do changes with boot process
- From the boot list remove everything and add only Windows to it

Things should work fine after this.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your Windows Installation disk (Windows 7 or 8 both will work). In the 'Install Now' window click repair your computer.

**FOR WINDOWS 7**

Click on Command Prompt in the new windows that appears.

**FOR WINDOWS 8**

First click Advanced Options and then command prompt.

**NOW FOLLOW BELOW STEPS**

Now in command prompt enter the below two lines:

bootrec.exe /fixmbr

bootrec.exe /fixboot

Restart your computer and you will boot to Windows successfully!